# Cordova / Android Studio 1.3.2 - How to add www folder as content root?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, intellij-idea

I imported an existing cordova project (.../platforms/android) into Android Studio **1.3.2**.
How can I add the www folder as another content root to this Android Studio project?

The provided help is kind of useless as it simply leads you to
[IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.0 Help/Configuring Content Roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-content-roots.html) which seems to be written for a different version.

When i follow the suggestion given there I simply can't find the function to add the www folder as another content root of the android module.